# How can I pass information from one website to another website securely?

Tags: database

I have two websites:

- Website A: is a template site that only allows for the use of JavaScript
- Website B: is run on a flask server that I have full control over, and where i have a lot of processing resources

I want to take data from website A and pass it to website B securely. I was thinking of constructing an API on website B that when called externally would add data to a database. Is there a way I can do this so that it can't be exploited? Particularly I'd like to avoid a malicious user calling the API a million times and crashing my database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can read this article about api authentification : https://nordicapis.com/3-common-methods-api-authentication-explained/

There is different methods but it usualy include a token that you pass on every request to your api server.

Comment: The question is though, how do I ensure that the token is hidden? like fundamentally it's the users browser that handles everything, which is basically like the user doing it themselves in the console, what would be really cool is if we could only do this on page load